# Mono.Cecil assembly references declared in XAML only

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpftoolkit, mono.cecil

I have a WPF appliation which uses the WPFToolkit.Extended from Codeplex for some controls.
The project file of the WPF application contains a reference to the WPFToolkit.Extended assembly.

For deployment purposes I'd like to have all assembly references for the WPF application which I query with Mono.Cecil:

```
assembly.SelectMany(asm => asm.Modules).SelectMany(m => m.AssemblyReferences)
```

Now I noticed that the WPFToolkit.Extended is not in the result list. I assume because it is referenced in XAML only.

Is there a better way to solve this than instantiating a dummy instance of that assembly in the code (according my experiments this will work)?